# MySQL combinations 2 coloumns as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

While creating a MySQL Table I want to make 2 coloumns as primary key
?
How can i do so?

I want to make primary key as `(admin_id, primary key)`

`create table version (admin_id varchar(20) primary key, versionid integer, employeeid float4)`

Comment: Do you mean a primary key `(admin_id, versionid)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate primary key constraint.  For instance, for `(admin_id, versionid)`:

```
create table version (
    admin_id varchar(20),
    versionid integer,
    employeeid varchar(20),
    constraint pk_version primary key (admin_id, versionid)
);
```

Note:  `float` is a really bad idea for an id, for many, many reasons.  Use `varchar`, `decimal`, or some sort of integer.

Comment: Multiple PRIMARY KEY are not allowed in MySQL